# Spring MVC HelloWorld

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run my helloWorld program using Spring web mvc but there is a problem in my JSP file .. it can't read the value of "message" attribute added to ModelMap .. the jsp page opens normally but it displays the jsp EL as it is ${message} .. not the value of message !!

### handler-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.shura" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>  
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

### HelloWorld.java

```
package com.shura;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World");
    return("hello");
}
```

}

### hello.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Spring MVC Hello World Example</h1>

<h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

### web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>handler</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>handler</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Add your web.xml, make sure that it has a correct version if it is to low it will not have EL enabled.

Comment: Would you please try model.addObject instead of model.addAttribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please change the version to 2.4 instead of 2.3 in the web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Also please check the URL that you are using to access the web page:

```
http://{ip address or localhost}:{port}/{web app context}/hello/
```

Comment: i changed the code but no change... also jstl-1.2.jar is available

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Will you try ctrl + F5 for refreshing the page?

Comment: Which app server (with which version) you are using for deployment?

Comment: i'm using built-in browser of eclipse .. i changed the html code to see if there is a reflection .. but no change in jsp EL

Comment: Did you try changing the version of web-app tag in web.xml from 2.3 to 2.4?

Comment: Would you please tell me the URL you are using to access the page?

Answer (score 0):

Here problems with your jsp page tag

for instant solution use below jsp code without taglib

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

is(/hello) request going to controller? I am guessing that you are accessing the jsp page directly and is not going via controller. Also, Can you change either request mapping URL or JSP name and try?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, when returning from the method printHello we have to return an object which contains view information and model information also.

Although you are forming model but what I see is that you are not returning it.

You are only returning a string which is understood as a view name.

So, you need to return an object of ModelAndView.

Comment: No you don't... The things you put in the `ModelMap` are automatically part of the model.

Comment: Exactly what @geoand posted.

Comment: Can you please try it. This is what I could manage to recall. Its been three years from the time I worked on SpringMVC. Anywasy, I will follow this post to know the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for downvote. It has made me realize that not everything I should answer. I should answer what I completely know.

Comment: I did what you said but no change !

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
public class HelloWorld {
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute();
    return new ModelAndView("hello","message", "Hello World");
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It won't. You are basically doing the same.

Comment: then i guess there might be something wrong with `EL`